# In a HTML page, i want to pick the value of a javascript with jsoup

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, jsoup

```
<html>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
        jQuery(function($) {
    L.marker([50.065407, 19.945104], {title: 'Cat'})
                        .bindPopup('<h3>Cat</h3><p><strong>color</strong>black<br><strong>Dog</strong>white</p>')
                        .addTo(map);
        </script>
    </html>
```

I need to get values from `<h3>` and `<strong>`.

```
script = doc.select("script");
```

but how to get: 
 
"Cat color black"
"Dog white" ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the text from a map marker popup?

Comment: Your snippet isn't html. It appears to be adding a marker on a 2d surface (a map?) through an API. That API might not necessarily add the popup to the DOM. We'd need more information about `L`, I assume, to figure it out.

Comment: I added more information

Comment: Get the content of the `script` element and then use a regex to extract what you want.

Comment: mt = doc.select("script");

                p = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+");
                m = p.matcher(doc.html());
                return String.valueOf(m);
                
                it returns me java.util.regex.Matcher@4167d5f8

Comment: You never close the anonymous function.